# when printing page with highcharts using javascript this.print() width values in css in @media print seem to be ignored

Tags: highcharts

When using @media print highcharts seems to ignore with width and height in the screen section and instead use the values from the display section.

This is preventing me from printing my entire web page with the highcharts on it since the charts are not the right size when printed.

See [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mlawrence85704/6WxgG/10/embedded/result/)

```
@media screen
    {


      .cont
        {
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;

        }
    }

 @media print
    {
        .no-Print{
            display: none;
        }


        .cont
        {
            width: 5%;
            height: 5%;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't ignore the styles. It just defines width in pixels for elements inside container. To see this, you can add set container's overflow to hidden:

```
.cont {
    width: 5%;
    height: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

(see: http://jsfiddle.net/6WxgG/15/embedded/result/)

AFAIK it's not possible to reasonably resize the chart using only CSS.